# Using Smarty, syntax error: unrecognized tag 'extends'

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Tried to googled, and the documentations, no luck.

#### default_shirts.tpl

```
<body>{block name="chicken"}{/block}</body>
```

chefsquad_rice.tpl

```
{extends file="default_shirts.tpl"}
```

#### chefsquad_rice.php

```
require ("../../libs/Smarty/Smarty.class.php");

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = '../../templates';
$smarty->compile_dir  = '../../templates_c';
$smarty->config_dir   = '../../configs';
$smarty->cache_dir    = '../../cache';

$smarty->debugging = false; //Disable to remove popup
$smarty->caching = false;

$smarty->display('../../templates/chefsquad_rice.tpl');
```

I am getting this error on the PHP page, I've tried everything and I'm stuck now. Any luck guys?

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in ../../templates/chefsquad_rice.tpl line 1]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'extends' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 585) in C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Samm's and Richard's Work\Richard's Work\htdocs\chefsquadent\Actual Website\libs\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1100

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parent page.

Check the below code :

```
$smarty->display('extends:../../templates/default_shirts.tpl|../../templates/chefsquad_rice.tpl');
```

> `$smarty->display('extends:parent.tpl|child.tpl|grandchild.tpl');`

Reference : https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.extends.tpl

Comment: `Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "extends:../../templates/default_shirts.tpl|../../templates/chefsquad_rice.tpl" in libs\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1100` I get this error code now, any idea?

Comment: could you try with absolute paths of template files?

Answer (score 0):

From your error, I think you use Smarty v2 (not v3). (Check source code of [Smarty.class.php](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/Smarty2/libs/Smarty.class.php) and [Smarty_Compiler.class.php](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/Smarty2/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php), which are exactly line that your error happened).

And `{extends}` isn't included in Smarty v2 (only v3 supported). Instead, you should use [`{include}`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl).

Example:

```
{include file="default_shirts.tpl"}
```